# Spark SQL convert dataset to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I convert a dataset obj to a dataframe?  In my example, I am converting a JSON file to dataframe and converting to DataSet.  In dataset, I have added some additional attribute(`newColumn`) and convert it back to a dataframe. Here is my example code:

```
val empData = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("multiline", "true").json(filePath)
```

.....

```
 import sparkSession.implicits._
    val res = empData.as[Emp]

    //for (i <- res.take(4)) println(i.name + " ->" + i.newColumn)

    val s = res.toDF();

    s.printSchema()

  }
  case class Emp(name: String, gender: String, company: String, address: String) {
    val newColumn = if (gender == "male") "Not-allowed" else "Allowed"
  }
```

But I am expected the new column name `newColumn` added in `s.printschema()`. output result.  But it is not happening?  Why?  Any reason?  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The schema of the output with `Product` `Encoder` is solely determined based on it's constructor signature. Therefore anything that happens in the body is simply discarded.

You can

```
empData.map(x => (x, x.newColumn)).toDF("value", "newColumn")
```

Comment: thanks .. final code part   val r = res.map(s => (s.name,s.gender,s.company,s.address,s.newColumn)).toDF("name", "gender", "company", "address", "newColumn"); .. is there any shortcut to pass parameter toDF . if class have more parameters then very tough to provide al the values . have any shortcut